# Unable to upgrade NodeJS version on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up a new EC2/Node instance via the Elastic Beanstalk console, but I'm unable to upgrade NodeJS as the button is grayed out.

[image: Change button grayed out]

I tried changing the version of NodeJS in the configuration section, but it didn't upgrade it. In the past either of the options have worked, but I'm not sure why the button is grayed out? I've also tried deploying a sample application and other (supported) versions of NodeJS in the config. I've tried restarting and rebuilding the environment with the new config, but it defaults to Node v4.3.0.

[image: Configuration options]

Has anyone encountered this? Am I missing something here? Thanks!

EDIT: [This guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-console.html#environments-console-configuration) states that the option to change configuration is available only when a new compatible version of the platform is available. However, I'm interested in updating NodeJS and not the overall OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are 2 different things, `v4.3.0` (in first image), is the version of the Amazon Linux OS. Is not related to node.

The second image shows the node version you are using (`6.10.0`). You can tweak that in the config dialog

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. It was weird that both the versions matched initially.